# Application crashes when throwing an exception

Tags: c++, exception

In the application I am writing, I make usage of exceptions for most of my error handling. I've not defined my own exception classes just yet, I merely did the following:

```
namespace Mage {
    typedef std::exception Exception;
}
```

This way I won't have to change all of my code when I define my own type later which should use the same interface.

That said, any exception crashes my application. Taking the above definition in mind, why would this crash?

```
void Mage::Root::initialize(Mage::String& p_log) {
    // initialize GLFW and GLEW.
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        throw new Mage::Exception("failed to initialize OpenGL");
        return;
    } else m_GLFWInitialized = true;
```

Whether I remove or keep 'new', it would still crash. Am I missing something? I've looked up tutorials but those don't get me any wiser.

I also catch the error right here:

```
try {
    MAGE_ROOT.initialize(Mage::String("Mage.log"));
} catch (Mage::Exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

The crash I'm getting is:

```
Debug Error!

Program: ...sual Studio 2010\Project\Mage3D\Binaries\Debug\Test.exe

R6010
- abort() has been called

(Press Retry to debug application)
```

Comment: How are you catching your exception?

Comment: I think, that place, *where* you throw the exception is also relevant. Generally throwing exceptions in destructors may result in such error.

Comment: You _are_ catching the exception, right?

Comment: I wasn't aware you -have- to catch the exception.

Comment: Even with a try/catch statement, the application still crashes. I'll update my question.

Comment: Can you simply post a piece of source? It may make a problem a lot easier to nail down.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `new` while throwing an exception. What if the exception is due to memory allocation problems?

Comment: @JesseBrands: You are throwing a pointer and catching a reference. See my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you are not catching your exception.

> I wasn't aware you -have- to catch the exception (*from the comments*)

Yes, you have to. If you do not catch a thrown exception, `std::terminate()` will be called. This is the intended behavior: exceptions exist to prevent programmers from *forgetting* about error handling.

This said, I suggest:

- throwing by value;
- catching by reference

For instance:

```
void foo()
{
    // ...
    throw std::logic_error("Error!");
    //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //    Throw by value (std::logic_error derives from std::exception)
    // ...
}

void bar()
{
    try
    {
        // ...
        foo();
        // ...
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //     Catch by reference
    {
        std::cout << e.what(); // For instance...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

With regards to the piece of code you posted, you are throwing a *pointer* and catching by *reference*. The handler won't match. And since there is no other matching handler, `std::terminate()` will be called.

Instead, you should throw your exception by value:

```
throw Mage::Exception("failed to initialize OpenGL");
```

And if the code you posted is indeed the one you are using, you will see that control is transferred to your handler.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, you're using Visual Studio (2010) for your project.  Unless you wrap your throw in a try/catch block, it will "sail through the roof" and be "handled" by the C++ runtime, which means calling abort().  You probably want something like this higher in the call stack:

```
try
{
   SomeFunctionThatUltimatelyThrows();
}
catch(Exception & e)
{
   // .. handle error - log, resume, exit, whatever
}
```

Note also Scott Meyers advice to always catch exceptions by reference.  The "exception":  If you're using MFC CExceptions though, you want to catch by pointer and call the Delete method for self-destructing heap-based exceptions.

Based on your edit, you may have a mismatch between throwing "by pointer" and catching "by reference".  If you've resolved that and are still not getting your catch block to execute, you could try debugging the abort() call by using the CRT SetAbortHandler to install your own abort function.  This could simply chain into the existing one, but would give an opportunity to set a breakpoint and examine the call stack to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

C++ try-catch-throw logic for dummies. Note that this does NOT cover RAII / stack-based allocation / destruction.

- When you throw an exception, an exception is said to be "propagating". It propagates up the call stack until it finds the first handler that can handle it (so it's caught) or until it's reached the root of your call stack.

  - If it is caught, execution continues from the point the exception is caught. The exception is destructed at the end of the catch block.
  - If it finds the root, it calls std::unhandled_exception, which usually calls std::terminate, which usually calls abort(). In short, everything's dropped ASAP.
- If you throw an exception while an exception is currently propagating, you would have two propagating at a time. Java and C# have cutesy ways of dealing with this, but this should never happen in the first place - there's no exception handler that is logically going to handle combinations of exceptions. Do not throw exceptions while one is currently propagating. This rule isn't too hard to hold even if you don't use std::uncaught_exception() which you shouldn't.
- While unwinding the stack / propagating the exception all objects found on the stack are destructed. These destructors should never throw an exception - after all, when destroying an object "fails", what else are you going to do after the destructor to fix it?
- Always throw by value, catch by reference. If you throw & catch by pointer, you will most likely leak something, which is impossible by reference. If you catch by value, you will slice off your derived exception types. Catch by reference.
- At the root of your software, include a catch-all - `catch(...)`. This doesn't allow you to find out what exactly you've caught, but at least you can crash safely. Do this also when the called code may throw "something" that you don't know.